# Tkinter returning a variable to main

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

Hi I have a program that runs the following way. When a user enters a number between 1-10 and hits the GO button 3 checboxes appear Left, Middle and Right. Upon the selection of only 1 checkbox a button Next appears. I disable the other ones after 1 is selected. I would like to return to the main program which checkbox was selected. How do I do this. I can do it through the Next button or through the checkbox selection. My code is below

```
import Tkinter as Tk
import ctypes


def setup_fc_error_message():
    lines = ['fc is out of range: Please Enter a value from 1-10:']
    MessageBox = ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxA
    MessageBox(None, "\n".join(lines), 'Setup Info', 0)

def check_fc_range(fc_user):
   # fc_float = si_units(fc_string_input)
#    fc_float = float(fc_string_input)
    fc_string_user = str(fc_user)
    if (fc_user)>=1 and (fc_user<=10):
         return (float(fc_user),fc_string_user)
    else:
         setup_fc_error_message()
         return check_fc_range()


class MainWindow(Tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        Tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.parent.title('Test')
        self.initialize()


    def var_states_d(self):
        return self.dvar

    def var_states_r(self):
        return self.rvar

    def var_states_l(self):
        return self.lvar


    def cdb(self):
#        print "variable is", self.dvar.get()
        self.dvar_state = self.dvar.get()
#        self.band_type = StringVar()
#        self.band_type.set('D')

        if self.dvar_state:
            self.cr = Tk.Checkbutton(self.parent, text='Middle', state='disable', variable=self.rvar,command = self.crb)
            self.cr.grid(row = 2, column = 1)

            self.cl = Tk.Checkbutton(self.parent, text='Right', state='disable', variable=self.lvar,command = self.clb)
            self.cl.grid(row = 2, column = 2)

            self.nextbutton = Tk.Button(self.parent, text='NEXT', command= self.var_states_d)
            self.nextbutton.grid(row=2,column=3)

        else:
            self.cr = Tk.Checkbutton(self.parent, text='Middle', variable=self.rvar,command = self.crb)
            self.cr.grid(row = 2, column = 1)

            self.cl = Tk.Checkbutton(self.parent, text='Right', variable=self.lvar,command = self.clb)
            self.cl.grid(row = 2, column = 2)

            self.nextbutton = Tk.Button(self.parent, text='NEXT', state='disable')
            self.nextbutton.grid(row=2,column=3)




    def crb(self):
#        print "variable is", self.rvar.get()

        self.rvar_state = self.rvar.get()
#        self.band_type = StringVar()
#        self.band_type.set('R')

        if self.rvar_state:
            self.cd = Tk.Checkbutton(self.parent, text='Left', state='disable', variable=self.dvar,command = self.cdb)
            self.cd.grid(row = 2, column = 0)

            self.cl = Tk.Checkbutton(self.parent, text='Right', state='disable', variable=self.lvar,command = self.clb)
            self.cl.grid(row = 2, column = 2)

            self.nextbutton = Tk.Button(self.parent, text='NEXT', command= self.var_states_r)
            self.nextbutton.grid(row=2,column=3)
        else:
            self.cd = Tk.Checkbutton(self.parent, text='Left', variable=self.dvar,command = self.cdb)
            self.cd.grid(row = 2, column = 0)

            self.cl = Tk.Checkbutton(self.parent, text='Right', variable=self.lvar,command = self.clb)
            self.cl.grid(row = 2, column = 2)

            self.nextbutton = Tk.Button(self.parent, text='NEXT', state='disable')
            self.nextbutton.grid(row=2,column=3)

    def clb(self):
#       print "variable is", self.lvar.get()

        self.lvar_state = self.lvar.get()
#        self.band_type = StringVar()
#        self.band_type.set('L')

        if self.lvar_state:
            self.cd = Tk.Checkbutton(self.parent, text='Left', state='disable', variable=self.dvar,command = self.cdb)
            self.cd.grid(row = 2, column = 0)

            self.cr = Tk.Checkbutton(self.parent, text='Middle', state='disable', variable=self.rvar,command = self.crb)
            self.cr.grid(row = 2, column = 1)

            self.nextbutton = Tk.Button(self.parent, text='NEXT', command= self.var_states_l)
            self.nextbutton.grid(row=2,column=3)

        else:
            self.cd = Tk.Checkbutton(self.parent, text='Left', variable=self.dvar,command = self.cdb)
            self.cd.grid(row = 2, column = 0)

            self.cr = Tk.Checkbutton(self.parent, text='Middle', variable=self.rvar,command = self.crb)
            self.cr.grid(row = 2, column = 1)

            self.nextbutton = Tk.Button(self.parent, text='NEXT', state='disable')
            self.nextbutton.grid(row=2,column=3)







    def initialize(self):
      #  self.frame = Tk.Frame(parent)
      #  self.frame.pack()

        self.fc_gui = Tk.DoubleVar(self.parent)

        self.fclabel1 = Tk.Label(self.parent, text = 'Please Enter a value between 1 and 10', fg = 'black', bg = 'yellow')
        self.fclabel1.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

        self.fcedit1 = Tk.Entry(self.parent, textvariable = self.fc_gui, bd = 5  )
        self.fcedit1.grid(row = 1, column = 0)

        self.fcbutton1 = Tk.Button(self.parent, text='GO', command = self.get_fc)
        self.fcbutton1.grid(row = 1, column = 1)


    def add_checkbox(self):

        self.dvar = Tk.IntVar()

        self.cd = Tk.Checkbutton(self.parent, text='Left', variable=self.dvar,command = self.cdb)
        self.cd.grid(row = 2, column = 0)


        self.rvar = Tk.IntVar()

        self.cr = Tk.Checkbutton(self.parent, text='Middle', variable=self.rvar,command = self.crb)
        self.cr.grid(row = 2, column = 1)

        self.lvar = Tk.IntVar()

        self.cl = Tk.Checkbutton(self.parent, text='Right', variable=self.lvar,command = self.clb)
        self.cl.grid(row = 2, column = 2)



    def get_fc(self):

        self.fc_user = self.fc_gui.get()
        if self.fc_user:
            if check_fc_range(self.fc_user):
                self.add_checkbox()
            return self.fc_user
######################################################GUI portion ##############################################

def main():

    root = Tk.Tk()
    app = MainWindow(root)
    fc_gui_user = app.get_fc()

    app.mainloop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: If only one button should be selected, then use Radiobuttons. Use the variable option with an Intvar or Stringvar to access results from anywhere in the program.  See section 52 of http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I cleaned up your MainWindow class removing the cdb, crb, cld functions so you only need one for each called `on_toggle` to make it more efficient. You'll also notice some slight changes in the `add_checkbox` function using `lambda` to pass in the value for that specific checkbutton. And since I combined the functions I did the same for the `var_state`s function.

I left the `Tk.IntVar` in there as maybe you might have needed them. Although I'm not sure what you're wanting to use them for with a Checkbutton.

As for your question, you already had a method of finding out which checkbox was selected so I'm not entirely sure what you're after, but I've outlined where you can check them.

```
class MainWindow(Tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.parent.title('Test')
        self.initialize()
        self.chk_buttons = [] # List holding each checkbutton
        self.var_states = [] # List holding each Invar for checkbutton
        self.clicked = False # Variable to know if a checkbutton is currently selected

    def get_var_states(self, i):
        # Return IntVar of clicked checkbutton
        return self.var_states[i]

    def on_toggle(self, pos):
#        print "variable is", self.dvar.get()
        self.dvar_state = self.dvar.get()
#        self.band_type = StringVar()
#        self.band_type.set('D')

        if not self.clicked:
            # Changes all except clicked checkbox to disabled
            # Altering state of existing widget
            for i, chk_btn in enumerate(self.chk_buttons):
                if i != pos:
                    chk_btn.configure(state='disable') 

            self.nextbutton = Tk.Button(self.parent, text='NEXT', command=lambda: self.get_var_states(pos))
            self.nextbutton.grid(row=2,column=3)

        # You can use these if statements to do something if a certain checkbutton is clicked
        # Alternately you can call self.get_var_states(pos) here, instead of adding the command
        # to the Next button so it runs when a checkbutton is clicked instead of when the Next button is clicked
            if pos == 0: # Left
                pass 

            if pos == 1: # Middle
                pass 

            if pos == 2: # Right
                pass

        else:
            # Changes all checkbox to normal
            for chk_btn in self.chk_buttons:
                chk_btn.configure(state='normal')

            self.nextbutton = Tk.Button(self.parent, text='NEXT', state='disable')
            self.nextbutton.grid(row=2,column=3)

        self.clicked = not self.clicked #Changes between True and False with each click


    def initialize(self):
      #  self.frame = Tk.Frame(parent)
      #  self.frame.pack()

        self.fc_gui = Tk.DoubleVar(self.parent)

        self.fclabel1 = Tk.Label(self.parent, text = 'Please Enter a value between 1 and 10', fg = 'black', bg = 'yellow')
        self.fclabel1.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

        self.fcedit1 = Tk.Entry(self.parent, textvariable = self.fc_gui, bd = 5  )
        self.fcedit1.grid(row = 1, column = 0)

        self.fcbutton1 = Tk.Button(self.parent, text='GO', command = self.get_fc)
        self.fcbutton1.grid(row = 1, column = 1)


    def add_checkbox(self):
        # Added lambda function passing in a value corresponding to the index position in the list
        self.dvar = Tk.IntVar()

        self.cd = Tk.Checkbutton(self.parent, text='Left', variable=self.dvar,command = lambda: self.on_toggle(0))
        self.cd.grid(row = 2, column = 0)

        self.rvar = Tk.IntVar()

        self.cr = Tk.Checkbutton(self.parent, text='Middle', variable=self.rvar,command = lambda: self.on_toggle(1))
        self.cr.grid(row = 2, column = 1)

        self.lvar = Tk.IntVar()

        self.cl = Tk.Checkbutton(self.parent, text='Right', variable=self.lvar,command = lambda: self.on_toggle(2))
        self.cl.grid(row = 2, column = 2)

        self.chk_buttons = [self.cd, self.cr, self.cl] # List of checkboxes
        self.var_states = [self.dvar, self.rvar, self.lvar] # List corresponding InvVar

    def get_fc(self):

        self.fc_user = self.fc_gui.get()
        if self.fc_user:
            if check_fc_range(self.fc_user):
                self.add_checkbox()
            return self.fc_user
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will try it out. I am converting a python script with user input into a gui. To do this do I just copy all my functions into the Class MainWindow (): ?

Comment: More or less with a little tinkering, it all depends on how you want to set it out. You can have other classes as well to help organise different aspects of your program.

Comment: I tried out the code but it seems it only enables the Next button when I check the last checkbox (right). If I hit Left and Middle it does not disable the other two checkboxes. Maybe this is easier if I use a radiobutton?